# Как подключить docker-toolbox к PhpStorm в windows?

Tags: windows, phpstorm, docker, docker-compose

Здравствуйте!

Я установил docker-toolbox, в нем запущена **docker-mahine** - **default** на ip **192.168.99.100**, все мои контейнеры отлично тут работают (с обычным докером были проблемы - не работали контейнеры какие отлично работали в mac/ubuntu )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работаю я в IDE PhpStorm в котором есть возможность запускать контейнеры, но для этого нудно подключить/зарегистрировать докер в IDE. Но тут он у меня не определяться или я пропустил какой-то шаг подключения(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Побывал и по TCP:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я не так делаю? Кто знает как подключить?

Answer (score 0):

сам столкнулся с этой проблемой
накопал, что надо заменить `tcp` на `https` в *Engine API URL*